# How to get only updated document from Firestore

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

Is there a way to get only the updated document from firestore instead of all the documents when using valueChanges

```
return this.afs.collection('users').doc(userId).collection('chat_users').valueChanges();
```

I have the following code and it returns all the documents when only one has changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [stateChanges()](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#statechanges) for this:

> **What is it?** - Returns an Observable of the most recent changes as a DocumentChangeAction[].
>
> **Why would you use it?** - The above methods return a synchronized array sorted in query order. stateChanges() emits changes as they occur rather than syncing the query order. ...

```
return this.afs.collection('users')
    .doc(userId)
    .collection('chat_users')
    .stateChanges(['modified'])
    .pipe(
        map((actions) => actions.map(a => {
            const data = a.payload.doc.data();
            const id = a.payload.doc.id;
            return { id, ...data };
        }))
    );
```